# How to Run SVN Commands and Shell Scripts using command prompt

Tags: java, tortoisesvn, telnet

I am trying to get an solution but i have found any thing  on it. I want to create an GuI Application where i am accepting **Host Port Number,User Name** and **Password** .

After a Successful connection i want to execute some Tortoise Svn Commands through GUI.
Then I want to run one shell Script.

Please help me for doing this.Thanks in Advance.

Thanks for reply I am Trying to connect to remote Host through Telnet or ssh and then i want to export data from svn on some destination folder. and then need to run a default.sh shell script which creates zip of extracted data and other stuff.

i am  using java 1.6, Tortoise Svn  1.6.16, My operating system is Win Xp.

Comment: Can you explain more thoroughly what you're trying to do? Also, with what language, toolkit, and operating system? You've mentioned Tortoise SVN, so I'm guessing Windows, but guessing is fraught with peril...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for reply I am Trying to connect to remote Host through Telnet or ssh and then i want to export data from svn on some destination folder. and then need to run a default.sh shell script which creates zip of extracted data and other stuff.

Comment: `@niraj:` To improve your question, click the "edit" button rather than using a comment. And you haven't addressed just about any of the things I mentioned. Again: What language do you intend to use? What toolkit/environment? What OS(es)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use Tortoise for this. Install the Subversion command-line client, and run your commands that way.
http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

Answer (score 1):

Look at [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/documentation.html#high-level-api). It might help you.

And for the record - all svn commands are the same everywhere, they does not depend on the client you are using. Tortoise is just one of implementations which calls the svn commands.

Comment: TortoiseSVN happens to be a client which does not call svn commands (and therefore, does not require svn to be installed) but has the corresponding dlls.